# Mobile push and mobile connect in Journey builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, administration, journeybuilder, mobileconnect, mobilepush

My account have been provisioned both Mobile connect,SMS (SKU 213452) and Mobile Push for Journey Builder (SKU 213451).

Both relationship manager and the salesforce marketing cloud support team claimed that the order and the access is granted.

However, I still do not find the interface include sms or mobile push as option in "Activities" in the journey builder.
[image]

Does anyone have a clue on the situation?
I have checked on the administration right as well but nothing else related can be enable.
Please let me know if there are further set up/condition need to meet before they are enable.

(For sure Mobile connect and Mobile push are already enabled in my account)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]Login to your marketing cloud account and go to the platform tab and click on Extension Manager. You should see JB for Mobile Connect and JB for Mobile Push as options. Click on Manage and search for the user you want to provision. Make sure a check mark is there against the user. Logout and log back in to check if this enables the required activities.

Comment: Thanks but we don't find the platform tab. How to set permission to gain access to the platform tab? The account is already having Administration rights.

Comment: Please open a ticket with support. Buying MC and MP will not provide activities within JB, they have to be activated.

Answer (score 1):

With the latest release of Journey Builder, SMS functionality is now available in Journey Builder without having to get it enabled.